# How to append percent sign from exported excel data in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

[image]

the persent is ok from line,but when i expert excel data ,the percent sign is gone, so how can i Append a percent sign in the exported excel

this is expert code:

```
tooltip: { 
pointFormat: '{point.y:.2f}%' 
},
exporting: { 
  buttons: { 
  exportButton: { 
   text: 'export excel', 
   onclick: function () { 
     this.downloadXLS(); 
   }, 
     symbol:'download', 
   }, 
  contextButton: { 
    enabled: false 
  },
  } 
},
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfY25.png)

Comment: Now the `%` is added by tooltip, so it doesn't exist in your data which is imported. Try to use this custom code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rg7k1j5c/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks bro, but still doesn't exist in the data from imported...............

Comment: Are you sure? Because the xls data is fetched from the table and it seems that the data includes the `%` in shared demo.

Comment: ye,but when i down load the xls data,the % is gone......u can see the pic, i copy your demo pic in my question , u can check...

Comment: I just tested my demo and it seems that it works fine. https://ibb.co/b7zyvvB

Comment: @SebastianWędzel ok thanks bro, i will double check